# Datasource details as System properties?

Tags: java, quarkus

Is it possible to pass the properties of a datasource to quarkus by using System properties or environment variables for example instead of using the application properties file, pass

```
-Dquarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ib24_booking?useSSL=false
```

so that the values can be passed differently according to the environment I am in.

Comment: Yes, that should work. Have you encountered any problems with it?

Answer (score 1):

It should work as you said. You can find more details here https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource